# fwrite() doesn't write the full string

Tags: c++, windows, fwrite

fwrite only writes 8 bytes, The file should contain "Hello, World!" however when I open it, it shows "Hello, W"

```
FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
const char* b = "Hello, World!\n";
fwrite(b, sizeof(char), sizeof(b), f);
fclose(f);
```

I've googled "fwrite doesn't write the full string" but I couldn't find something similar to my problem.

Comment: Did you check how much `sizeof(b)` is

Comment: `sizeof(b)` is the same as `sizeof(const char*)`. You want `strlen(b)`.

Comment: sizeof(b) is 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(b)` returns the size of the pointer, not the length of the string. You could use `strlen` to get it though:

```c
fwrite(b, sizeof(char), strlen(b), f);
// Here ----------------^
```